# Pipenv installing with the wrong python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pipenv

I'm creating a fresh new python environment, and want to use 3.11.0. I've installed python 3.11 and updated pip.

Running either  `python -V` or `pipenv run python -V` both return `Python 3.11.0`
But when I go to install my dependencies (scikit-image) I get the following error:

`pipenv install`

```
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/attr/_make.py:778: RuntimeWarning: Running interpreter doesn't sufficiently support code object introspection.  Some features like bare super() or accessing __class__ will not work with slotted classes.
  set_closure_cell(cell, cls)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in _main
...
```

It looks like it's trying to use python version 2.7 for the installation. WHY.
I also tried a suggestion to install python through pipenv:

`pipenv --python 3.11.0 install`

Which gives the error:

```
Warning: Python 3.11.0 was not found on your system...
Would you like us to install CPython 3.11.0 with Pyenv? [Y/n]:
```

Choosing yes does some *stuff* but doesn't fix the issue, nothing changes.